# How to log application usage to website

Tags: java

I'm looking for a method to see how often people use my application and some small usage stats about that usage, e.g. Time Of Day (derived from the message time), duration of usage (program statistic), etc.

The application is written in Java and already connects to the internet, so I know I can send/request information from websites.

My question, is how best to do this? I know I could use Google Analytics and "ping" a specific web page, but ideally I'd like the extra statistics too, can that be done with GA? How do I separate that traffic out of the other GA stats?

Are there existing code snippets I could utilise?

What do I need the server to do? I have hosting with SSH access, MySQL, etc. So can install packages if needed.

**Edited to add**

This is not a web application, it's a local program that runs on a client machine and connects to the internet to gather data. So there's no web pages that I can insert java code or other scripts into for true web analytics.

This is why I was thinking that I would have to "ping" or "poke" (No idea what the correct terms are) a specific web address, perhaps a PHP page that would record the statistics.

The statistics that I would like to gather are:

- IP Address (ONLY to determine the unique visitor and perhaps country of origin)
- Time of execution (from the time the statistic was generated)
- Number of items processed (program statistic)
- Execution duration (program generated statistic)

As the program is usually run by the user an average of once per day, I don't anticipate massive load on the server (famous last words!)

**Edited for clarification**

The application is a CLI based (no GUI or web browser, web server, or other web application technologies are used). The application runs locally on a user's machine, collects information on various files, downloads information on those files from the internet (yes, using a URL connection), and compiles that information into a database.

I have no view of or access to, the users of the application. I do have a website that I use Google Analytics to see who visits and where from, all the usually stats.

I want to be able to capture a small bunch of stats (explained above) each time the application is run so I know that the application is being used and by how many users and what for.

I had thought I might be able to call a PHP web page with some arguments that could then be added to a database, e.g. http://omertron.com/stats?IP=192.168.2.0|processed=23|duration=270

Or can Google Analytics be used to log that information some how? I can't find much in the documentation about how I would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are:

- Tagging Systems (like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/))
- Access Log File Analysis

With tagging you create an account with Google Analytics and add some specific JavaScript code you will get from Google, into the relevant places of your code, this allows the browser of your visitors to connect to GA and get captured there.

The Access log file can hold all information about all sessions. There is a lot of detail data generated, so data has to be Extracted, Transformed and Loaded (ETL) to a database. The evaluation can be then performed in nearly real-time. You can create some dashboard application that does the ETL and displays the status of you application.

A third option would be to combine tagging and log file analysis. This will give you more precise results.

Comment: As explained in other comments, this isn't a web application its a CLI application that connects to the web, so there's not really an opportunity to insert JS into the program.  I was wondering if something like Google Analytics could collect information from a "dummy" web page that I could request from the server and therefore log information about the fake visit?

Comment: The way Google Analytics works, is by checking their access log files and offering a very nice web application to visualize the results for every account. Since you have your own web server somewhere, you could check the access information yourself. It is easy to add some code that opens a URLConnection and reads the page. This access will be logged. Check your log file and get the access information. If you need sample code add another comment here.

Comment: Ok, either I'm not understanding what you mean, or you're not understanding what I want to do. I'll update the question.

Comment: Let me put down what i understand: You have a CLI application. This application is run by many computers in different locations. You want to know their IPs and timestamps of when they run the application. You add a URLConnection to your site at the start of the program execution and another at exiting. They access your web server, the accesses are logged. You read the log file and know who, from where and for how long.

Comment: And yes you can avoid the log file story, if you pass the IP and the running time through the URL to your web server. You will need a small web application that will update your MySQL database every time the application is exiting.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this list of [web analytics software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software).  Lots of free packages there, and once you find one that suits your needs, you'll be able to frame your question specifically to the challenges in using that particular package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't a web application, so I'm not sure how the web analytics would really help, other than as an option to replace Google Analytics?

Comment: Oh sorry, I assumed it was a web application.

Comment: My mistake for not clarifying in the question, I've updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, my thoughts are you would need a framework to accomplish this.

The java application should be able to asynchronously log every event that is happening in the application.

In google analytics you can define names and push events for those specific names. If you would be able to use the following api, I dont think you need to ping a specific web page to use google analytics.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

I have not used this api, hope this helps!

Comment: I've clarified the question (I hope) to indicate that I'm not after realtime statistics per-se, rather a way of logging how many users I have and what size of processing they do with the application